# Flutter plugin path_provider is not being installed

Tags: android, flutter, dart, package

I have been trying to install flutter package [path_proveder](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider). But I do not know for what reason it is giving error. I need to use it in production app. One reason that might cause this error for using the flutterToast which requires minsdk 21.Can someone please fix this?

```
error: package io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider does not exist
  flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin());
```